# C++ allocation, construction and destruction questions

Tags: c++

Q1. In the following line of code, what happens first: memory allocation, or the constructor call?

```
int *ptr = new int();
```

Q2. What is the difference between the following three approaches to delete an object?

1. If an object is destroyed with `DELETE` operator; is it's destructor invoked?
2. If a destructor is called explicitly (e.g. `a1.~A()`) to destroy the object?
3. The object simply goes out of scope (i.e. Neither an explicit destructor call nor the `DELETE` operator used).

What would be the behavior if the destructor is private or protected?

Comment: give this a meaningful title and ask 2 separate questions if they are unrelated.

Comment: As Evan said, try to format your questions so that they might benefit others. If you have two questions, ask them separately, and give each a meaningful title. That way, the next time someone encounters the same problem, they can search and will find your question.

Comment: I have 2 doubts also - one being that this is not a homework question and the other being that someone is going to do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

OK, well I've given your questions a somewhat meaningful title, so I'll try to answer them as well. (Though you really should put multiple questions in multiple postings).

**Q1**. The allocation happens first. This is clearly the case because the object **doesn't exist** until it is allocated. Only then can the constructor run and give the object a value.

**Q2**.

```
1. If an object is destroyed with DELETE operator. Will destructor be called?
```

Yes.

```
2. If a destructor is called explicitly (e.g. a1.~A()) to destroy the object?
```

There is no real question here.

```
3. Neither explicit destructor call is made nor DELETE operator is used to destroy the object but object goes out of scope.
```

This question is ambiguous. The delete aspect of it implies the object was allocated on the heap, in which case it never goes out of scope... But the pointer to the object **can** go out of scope. If this is what you are talking about, then you have a memory leak.

However, if you are talking about a stack allocated object, then its destructor will be called when it goes out of scope.